# How come when I use eclipse Window Builder with graphics, it doesn't work?

Tags: java, debugging

I'm trying to add a rectangle to my JFrame with Window Builder and it gives me a syntax error, I tried all the things that can be the issue but Eclipse doesn't give me a hint of why it's not working. I tried to think on what's the issue but nothing came into mind.

This is my code:

```
package com.cookie.clicker;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PathFinder extends JPanel {

private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                PathFinder window = new PathFinder();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public PathFinder() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    PathFinder pf = new PathFinder();
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    pf.paint(null);

}
public void paint(Graphics g) 
{ 
    // set Color for rectangle 
    g.setColor(Color.red); 

    // draw a rectangle by drawing four lines 
    g.drawLine(100, 100, 100, 300); 
    g.drawLine(100, 300, 300, 300); 
    g.drawLine(300, 300, 300, 100); 
    g.drawLine(300, 100, 100, 100); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Well, `pf.paint(null);` there's a `NullPointerException` ... but since `PathFinder` is `JPanel` and you've not added it to any kind of window ... nothing is been shown

Comment: Oh, and Window Builder - any of them, best to avoid them till you have a better working knowledge of how the Swing API works

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you might like to start with

- [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html)

You'll also probably want to take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) to get a better understanding of how components get laid out

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PathFinder extends JPanel {

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    PathFinder finder = new PathFinder();
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.add(finder);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 400);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // set Color for rectangle 
        g.setColor(Color.red);

        // draw a rectangle by drawing four lines 
        g.drawLine(100, 100, 100, 300);
        g.drawLine(100, 300, 300, 300);
        g.drawLine(300, 300, 300, 100);
        g.drawLine(300, 100, 100, 100);
    }
}
```